# Exception when doing snapshot in OnPaintSurface

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, skiasharp

I am currently working on a Proof Of Concept project with SkiaSharp. I am very happy with the library, especially that you can use the powerful Skia library with C#. Unfortunately I now get an unhandle exception when using snapshots (mouse move). For the final goal I need a canvas of 8000x2000 pixels. When the canvas is smaller (300x400) the exception is not occuring. I hope someone knows what causes it. It could also be that I don't really understand the concept yet.

Also try to use SaveLayer but was not working as expected!

**Purpose**
Want to implement a Drag and drop function with SkiaSharp.

When the mouse moves, a snapshot is taken; then draw what has changed. When the OnPaintSurface has been called 80 times or so, the exception occurs.

**Expectations**

1. No exception
2. propose a different approach so that the Exception no longer occurs
3. It may also be that there is a bug in the SkiaSharp;SkiaSharp.Views.Blazor library

```
private void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas; // 8000x2000
    SKRect rect1 = new SKRect(0, 0, e.Info.Rect.Width, e.Info.Rect.Height);

    if (firstRun)
    {
        DrawBackground(e);
        layerBackGround = e.Surface.Snapshot();

        firstRun = false;
    }
    else
    {
        canvas.DrawImage(layerBackGround, rect1);

        // Draw something permanent

        layerBackGround = e.Surface.Snapshot(); // Here the exception is raised

        // Draw something temporary
        using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint { Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke, Color = SKColors.Red })
        {
            canvas.DrawCircle(mouseLocation, 100, paint);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Restore Snapshot Number Restore {counterSnapshots++}");
    }
}

private void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseLocation = new SKPoint((float)e.OffsetX, (float)e.OffsetY);

    skiaView.Invalidate();
}

> Uncaught Error 63124824
    at ___cxa_throw (localhost꞉7040/_framework/dotnet.7.0.12.y6rpn8jldv.js:1897:7)
    at $operator new(unsigned long) (wasm/05035f22:1:7760148)
    at $SkData::PrivateNewWithCopy(void const*, unsigned long) (wasm/05035f22:1:253631)
    at $SkData::MakeWithCopy(void const*, unsigned long) (wasm/05035f22:1:253980)
    at $MakeRasterCopyPriv(SkPixmap const&, unsigned int) (wasm/05035f22:1:3344311)
    at $SkMakeImageFromRasterBitmapPriv(SkBitmap const&, SkCopyPixelsMode, unsigned int) (wasm/05035f22:1:3345209)
    at $SkMakeImageFromRasterBitmap(SkBitmap const&, SkCopyPixelsMode) (wasm/05035f22:1:3345552)
    at $SkSurface_Raster::onNewImageSnapshot(SkIRect const*) (wasm/05035f22:1:3347489)
    at $SkSurface::makeImageSnapshot() (wasm/05035f22:1:3351341)
    at $sk_surface_new_image_snapshot (wasm/05035f22:1:5273126)
    at $do_icall (wasm/05035f22:1:5366088)
    at $do_icall_wrapper (wasm/05035f22:1:5361988)
    at $interp_exec_method (wasm/05035f22:1:5299397)
    at $interp_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5294797)
    at $mono_jit_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:7352181)
    at $do_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5907916)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke_checked (wasm/05035f22:1:5907796)
    at $mono_runtime_try_invoke_span (wasm/05035f22:1:5927157)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke_span_checked (wasm/05035f22:1:5927774)
    at $ves_icall_InternalInvoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5729477)
    at $ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw (wasm/05035f22:1:5759520)
    at $do_icall (wasm/05035f22:1:5366277)
    at $do_icall_wrapper (wasm/05035f22:1:5361988)
    at $interp_exec_method (wasm/05035f22:1:5299397)
    at $interp_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5294797)
    at $mono_jit_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:7352181)
    at $do_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5907916)
    at $mono_runtime_try_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5909851)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5918698)
    at $mono_wasm_invoke_method_ref (wasm/05035f22:1:7777494)
    at Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method_ref (localhost꞉7040/_framework/dotnet.7.0.12.y6rpn8jldv.js:8654:129)
    at _Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_InvokeDotNet (dotnet.generated.invalid/_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_InvokeDotNet:29:5)
    at invokeDotNetFromJS (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:45224)
    at g (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1621)
    at invokeMethod (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3812)
    at <anonymous> (C:\Users\r.gombert\.nuget\packages\skiasharp.views.blazor\2.88.6\staticwebassets\SKHtmlCanvas.js:104:38)
    --- requestAnimationFrame ---
    at requestAnimationFrame (C:\Users\r.gombert\.nuget\packages\skiasharp.views.blazor\2.88.6\staticwebassets\SKHtmlCanvas.js:98:41)
    at requestAnimationFrame (C:\Users\r.gombert\.nuget\packages\skiasharp.views.blazor\2.88.6\staticwebassets\SKHtmlCanvas.js:68:33)
    at invokeJSFromDotNet (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3219)
    at Gt (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:62634)
    at Ii (localhost꞉7040/_framework/dotnet.7.0.12.y6rpn8jldv.js:5:71974)
    at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (localhost꞉7040/_framework/dotnet.7.0.12.y6rpn8jldv.js:7677:71)
    at $do_icall (wasm/05035f22:1:5366372)
    at $do_icall_wrapper (wasm/05035f22:1:5361988)
    at $interp_exec_method (wasm/05035f22:1:5299397)
    at $interp_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5294797)
    at $mono_jit_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:7352181)
    at $do_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5907916)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke_checked (wasm/05035f22:1:5907796)
    at $mono_runtime_try_invoke_span (wasm/05035f22:1:5927157)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke_span_checked (wasm/05035f22:1:5927774)
    at $ves_icall_InternalInvoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5729477)
    at $ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw (wasm/05035f22:1:5759520)
    at $do_icall (wasm/05035f22:1:5366277)
    at $do_icall_wrapper (wasm/05035f22:1:5361988)
    at $interp_exec_method (wasm/05035f22:1:5299397)
    at $interp_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5294797)
    at $mono_jit_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:7352181)
    at $do_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5907916)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke_checked (wasm/05035f22:1:5907796)
    at $mono_runtime_try_invoke_span (wasm/05035f22:1:5927157)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke_span_checked (wasm/05035f22:1:5927774)
    at $ves_icall_InternalInvoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5729477)
    at $ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw (wasm/05035f22:1:5759520)
    at $do_icall (wasm/05035f22:1:5366277)
    at $do_icall_wrapper (wasm/05035f22:1:5361988)
    at $interp_exec_method (wasm/05035f22:1:5299397)
    at $interp_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5294797)
    at $mono_jit_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:7352181)
    at $do_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5907916)
    at $mono_runtime_try_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5909851)
    at $mono_runtime_invoke (wasm/05035f22:1:5918698)
    at $mono_wasm_invoke_method_ref (wasm/05035f22:1:7777494)
    at Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method_ref (localhost꞉7040/_framework/dotnet.7.0.12.y6rpn8jldv.js:8654:129)
    at _Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet (dotnet.generated.invalid/_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet:29:5)
    at beginInvokeDotNetFromJS (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:45087)
    at b (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1998)
    at invokeMethodAsync (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3866)
    at <anonymous> (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:11414)
    at invokeWhenHeapUnlocked (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:47333)
    at S (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:58698)
    at A (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:11383)
    at dispatchGlobalEventToAllElements (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:13968)
    at onGlobalEvent (localhost꞉7040/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:13161)
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (0x9c38) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (0x6960) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (0x18f4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x880 has exited with code 0 (0x0).




`
```